# Form table from PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I met problem, that, I believe, you can help me with.

I have next array:

JSON:

```
{
"1":{
"01:00":"1",
"02:00":""
},
"2":{
"01:00":"3",
"02:00":""
},
"3":{
"01:00":"23",
"02:00":""
},
"4":{
"01:00":"234",
"02:00":""
},
"5":{
"01:00":"234",
"02:00":""
},
"6":{
"01:00":"",
"02:00":""
},
"7":{
"01:00":"",
"02:00":""
}
}
```

PHP:

```
array (
    1 => array ( '01:00' => '1', '02:00' => '', ),
    2 => array ( '01:00' => '3', '02:00' => '', ),
    3 => array ( '01:00' => '23', '02:00' => '', ),
    4 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    5 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    6 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
    7 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
)
```

I am trying to put right values to right places, but I am at dead end :(

Can you help me with the table generator for this array.

It should look like this with values in inputs:
[image]

First line is quite static:

```
    echo "<table><tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        echo "<td>$days[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

And then problems starts.

Comment: This is asking you to change quite a bit so, just a comment: `$days = array ( '01:00' => array ('1','3','23','234','234','',''), '02:00=> array ('','','','','','',''));` and than `foreach ($days as $hours) { echo "<table><tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $hours) . "</td></tr></table>"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code

```
<?php
$days = array (
    1 => array ( '01:00' => '1', '02:00' => '', ),
    2 => array ( '01:00' => '3', '02:00' => '', ),
    3 => array ( '01:00' => '23', '02:00' => '', ),
    4 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    5 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    6 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
    7 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
);

echo "<table border='1'><thead><th>0</th>";

foreach($days as $k=>$v){   
    echo "<th>".$k."</th>"; 
}
echo "</thead><tbody>";

$rows = array_keys($days[1]);//edited

foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row."</td>";
    foreach($days as $key=>$val){
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='txt".$key."' value='".$days[$key][$row]."' style='width:40px;' />";//edited
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";


?>
```

Comment: kudos for putting in the extra effort, but you forgot to give the inputs a value :P, this  just makes a table of empty inputs.

Comment: lol i'm not the asker. I posted a competing answer, actually. just admiring your work :P

Comment: poster isn't notified of your comments until he comments on your post. If you want to ask him you should comment on the question, not on your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is loop over the y and x axes of the table and pull the value from the array.

```
$array = array (
    1 => array ( '01:00' => '1', '02:00' => '', ),
    2 => array ( '01:00' => '3', '02:00' => '', ),
    3 => array ( '01:00' => '23', '02:00' => '', ),
    4 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    5 => array ( '01:00' => '234', '02:00' => '', ),
    6 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
    7 => array ( '01:00' => '', '02:00' => '', ),
);

echo "<table>\n";
for ($y = 0; $y < count(reset($array)); $y++) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    for ($x = 0; $x <= count($array); $x++) {
        echo "\t\t<td>";
        if ($y == 0) {
            echo $x;
        }
        elseif (isset($array[$x])) {
            echo $array[$x]["0$y:00"];
        }
        else {
            echo "0$y:00";
        }
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\n</table>";
```

Here is the output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01:00</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you've got an array of *arrays*. When you loop through the array, you then need to loop through the inner array.

Personally, I like while loops, and if you don't mind doing it in reverse, this example should help.

```
function makeTableFromArray($array){
    $array = array_values($array);
    $tbl = "<table>";
    $i = count($array);
    while($i--){
        $tbl .= "<tr>";
        $row = array_values($array[$i]);
        $n = count($row);
        while($n--){
            $tbl .= "<td>".$row[$n]."</td>";
        }
        $tbl .= "</tr>";
    }
    $tbl .= "</table>";
    return $tbl;
}
```

Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/L5Wfu

**Edit** if you don't like doing it in reverse, you can reverse the array first: `makeTableFromArray(array_reverse($array));`